# Trying to create a virtual environment in python 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, virtualenv, python-3.9

I have a final for school that requires me to make a Django project. I installed python 3.9 on my Mac fine but when I try to run `virtualenv venv`, I get this error `virtualenv: error: argument dest: the destination . is not write-able at /Users/BUS`

I am not sure where else I would be able to write in the virtual env. I'm new to this so I don't really know where to go from here? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You don't have write permission in the folder you are trying to create the venv in.

Answer (score 0):

you can give your project directory write and execute permission by running this command `chmod u+x /YOUR/PATH/TO/PROJECT/SCRIPT` and if it doesn't help try sudo, also i'm no expert but learnt a thing that if you run python in any 'ix' systems to have passwords of root setup as then if you run scripts on your workstation chances are the command `chmod` with `sudo` gonna break privileges sooner or later, hope this helps, lmk.